# Why does my substring work when writing it like this?

Tags: javascript

Just a quick question regarding the behavior of my code: I just wanted to remove the first and last character of a string in JavaScript. So this is what my code looks like (it actually works the way it is supposed to work):

```
var element = "<LightName>";
element = element.substring(1, element.length - 1);
```

But why does it remove the last character as well when using -1? Shouldn't the length of the string at the time of element.length theoretically be still 11 (because the substring hasn't been executed yet) so I tell it to substring starting at index 1 with a length of 10.

Might be a quite confusing question, but perhaps someone can clearify it a little bit...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp), the substring method signature is:

```
string.substring(from, to)
```

This means that the second parameter is not the length of the substring, but the end position.

Comment: Oh ok it seems like I misunderstood substring then. If it's the to-position it absolutely makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: What the OP was thinking of was [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Comment: @Jongware That's right, it's because I mixed this with PHP. +1 because I didn't even know there was an equivalent method in JS as well.

Answer (score 2):

.substring has begin position and end position as parameters.
.substr has offset and length as parameters

for example:

```
var a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
var s = a.substring(5, 11) // fghijk
var s2 = a.substr(5, 11) // fghijklmnop
```

Answer (score 1):

Argument to substring is: `substring(FROM_INDEX, TO_INDEX)`

Index starts at 0 and goes till `length - 1`.

If string is of 11 characters length the index of string starts at 0 and ends at 10.

So if the string is `"abcd"`, you are taking a substring from index 1 to 4 (length) - 1, so you get `"bcd"`

**In your case (TO SKIP THE BRACKETS):**

```
var element = "<LightName>";
element = element.substring(1, element.length - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it's NOT -2 ;). I understood now though, it's because the second parameter is not the length but the to-position.

Comment: Glad to help. A typo mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you return everything except the first and the last character from the string. Since you start at 0, you will get the correct result if you substract 1 from the overall length.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp (i know w3 schools isnt the best place to quote but it shows it clearly)

```
string.substring(from, to)
```

Its not the length it the "to" argument, Which hasnt changed until the whole line has run

Answer (score 1):

Because the length of your string is 11. Your function says, get the substring from index 1 to index (11 - 1) 10. However, substring does not include the last index. So effectively you get the substring from index 1 to index 9.

Answer (score 1):

```
  .substring(first,second);
```

first argument is start position using starting index as 0.
second argument is end position but it is exclusive means from first to second but second is not included.